# I want to create an android app translator

Tags: android-activity

My problem is I want to create an android app translator that will translate our own dialect in the Philippines, and my other problem is that I don't know how to create that dialect and how will I apply it on my app. Please help. Thanks

Comment: So what exactly are you asking us?

Comment: How can I apply this in eclipse ADT? or ways?

Comment: Do you want to create a translator? Or only a single predefined dialect that you can use in Eclipse? Or do you want to translate a single app?

Comment: A translator that has a database of our own dialect.

Comment: That seems to be too broad a topic for Stackoverflow. The amount of processing required to not only translate but also hold the various classifiers and decision trees would be hard pressed to run on a phone if you want to do actual translations instead of just word lookups/replacements.

Comment: Does sphinx toolkit can help me with my problem?